# the insert statement in child table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to insert in child table , taking the [ACCNO] id and its count value from parent table    ,and then inserting [ACCNO] in the FK of child table and count against each [ACCNO] , but some error still there

```
INSERT INTO [test1].[dbo].[star_schema]
           (
           [ACCNO],
           [book_frequency])
     VALUES
           (SELECT  [books_dimension] .ACCNO , count(books_dimension .[ACCNO]) as book_frequency
            FROM         [books_dimension]  
                         group by [ACCNO] having (COUNT(*)>1) order by book_frequency  desc)
GO
```

Its giving error near SELECT  and in very last bracket.
I also like to mention that in table [star_schema] , the id is star_int which is identity –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need no `VALUES` and `ORDER BY` keyword when inserting from select, do like this:

```
INSERT INTO [test1].[dbo].[star_schema]([ACCNO], [book_frequency])
SELECT  
  [books_dimension].ACCNO, 
  count(books_dimension.[ACCNO]) as book_frequency
FROM [books_dimension]  
group by [ACCNO] 
having COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: thanks for reply , I checked but its giving error near desc , I removed desc but then 0 rows inserted , I also checked by removing group by , also checked with putting and removing brackets .

Comment: I also like to mention that in table [star_schema]  , the id is star_int which is identity

Comment: (0 row(s) affected),after new answer

Comment: my mistake , as book_dimension as unique rows , so its count cant be more then 1 , thanks once again for your posting